# TransactionScope alternative without DTC

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, transactions, transactionscope, msdtc

are there any alternative to transactionScope which does not need to enable DTC??

In the transaction I need to make two operations:

1. Create one user (using membership - sql membership provider)
2. Do one insert operation.

Comment: In my experience setting `Enlist=false` in the connection string caused `TransactionScope` not to work at all; no updates were enlisted in the available `TransactionScope`. I verified this using a Standard SQL Trace that included Transaction Events against an Entity Framework 6 application.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TransactionScope uses the LTM - Lightweight Transaction Manager in .Net. Only if you open more than one connection in the same transaction or go between databases, should TransactionScope promote the transaction to the 2PC-based TX-manager, DTC.

For MS SQL Server 2008 and above, the DTC will become involved only if you are opening connections to *different* DBs. OR if you are opening connections in the same transactions from multiple threads EXCEPT if you are using `DependentTransaction` which is what you should enlist in your global transaction if you want to do threading.

As a side-point: I have some support for the multi-threading story in [Castle.Transactions](https://github.com/castleproject/Castle.Transactions).

Side-point #2: If you use TransactionScope, make sure to declare the IsolationLevel explicitly otherwise you're serializing all your transactions (IsolationLevel.Serializable)!

Comment: Almost right. Only if you open _different_ connections (SQL Server 2008+) will the transaction escalate (if you are using the same connection string, you will still be using the LTM).

Comment: @Pedre - For a _distributed_ transaction, you need a transaction manager. No if buts or maybes.

Comment: @Oded, yes it differs between version of SQL Server too.

Comment: @MarcGravell - Not on the same DB/Server, as far as I have seen.

Comment: I think that 2005 was like I described and 2008 supports like Oded describes.

Comment: @Pedre It might depend on your implementation of the membership provider.

Comment: I think you can trigger DTC-ness through having multiple connections open in multiple threads, even if it's to the same DB, but if they are using the same transaction.

Comment: @Henrik I am using System.Web.Security.MembershipProvider. is it correct?

Comment: iirc, if several databases or nested connections are used, then transaction will be escalated to distributed. Correct?

Comment: @abatishchev I think it should be possible with Server 2008 to open two connections from the same thread for the same transaction, as they are pooled internally.

Comment: A bit late to the party here, but @Henrik, you're saying you can avoid DTC when opening multiple connections from multiple threads to the same database in a single transaction by using DependentTransaction? From where do you have this information? I'm having trouble making that exact case work using SQL Server 2013, so starting to doubt this statement. :)

Comment: @Oded  ***using the same connection string***, if I open different connections (SQL Server 2012) within `TransactionScope` the transaction escalate (DTC). Why ?

Answer (score 2):

Add `Enlist=false` in the connection string of your Membership.

```
connectionString="Data Source=xxx;Initial Catalog=xxx;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=xxx;Password=xxx;Enlist=false"
```

This is my use case:

```
using (TransactionScope tScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    MembershipCreateStatus createStatus;
    Membership.CreateUser(model.Email, model.Password, model.Email, null, null, true, model.Id, out createStatus);

    if (createStatus == MembershipCreateStatus.Success)
    {
       Roles.AddUserToRole(model.Email, "Administrator");
       _UpdatePersonnelAccess(model);
       _UpdatePersonnelHasAccess(model);
       _SendEmail_Welcome(model);
       PersonSessionLog.ManageSession(model);
    }
    else
       ViewBag.Message = "Error";

    tScope.Complete();
}
```

My application is published in Amazon EC2 while the database is in Amazon RDS. DTC is not supported in RDS that's why I also needed a way to prevent escalation to DTC. Btw, I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. I have 2 databases - ASPNETDB, data DB

Thanks to Paul [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409020/how-to-share-a-connection-between-ef-dbcontext-and-aspnet-membership-to-avoid-tr)!

Comment: ***Enlist=false*** not uses _Transaction_ ?