# the promote method returned an invalid value for the distributed transaction only in azure

Tags: asp.net, linq, sql-server-2008, azure-web-app-service

I am using Azure Web App to host the site

Used asp.net using vb.net and sql server hosted on an azure vm

A strange error "the promote method returned an invalid value for the distributed transaction" and very little information on web.

I am using it in **transaction scope**

where **MainMethod** calls **MethodA** & **MethodB** wrapped inside a **transactionscope** and each methods are further using **transactionscope** individually.

I don't get error running locally.

I get this error only in Azure Web App services.

Any suggestions highly welcome.

Answer (score 9):

The error indicates that your transaction is getting ***promoted*** to a distributed transaction. Distributed Transactions rely on **MSDTC** which uses **DCOM** protocol internally and DCOM will not work in Azure Webapps. A LTM (Lightweight transaction) gets promoted to a distributed transaction if you open multiple connections (Connection.open) within the same TransactionScope.

You can either ensure that only a single sqlconnection is opened in a transactionscope, or try changing your code to use SqlTransactions instead of TransactionScope or distributed transactions. In some articles it is also mentioned that if you use `ENLIST=FALSE` in connection string then elevation to MSDTC wont happen but not sure if that is a viable solution if multiple connections are opened in same transaction scope.

Also check these out

- [TransactionScope alternative without DTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11243855/transactionscope-alternative-without-dtc)
- [How to share a connection between EF DbContext and AspNet Membership to avoid transactions escalating to DTC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12409020/how-to-share-a-connection-between-ef-dbcontext-and-aspnet-membership-to-avoid-tr)